# Ruby win32api ShowWindow from taskbar

Tags: ruby, winapi, tk-toolkit, taskbar

I've been programming a desktop application with ruby/tk. Using the win32api gem, I've managed to hide and set my program icon to work in the taskbar. The icon can be found succesfully and the texttip works etc.

Now I'd like for the app window to maximize when the taskbar icon is clicked, or show a menu, but I have no idea how to reference this icon. After an exhausting googling sessions of a few hours I've yet to encounter anything to help me solve my problem.

Comment: The taskbar and its buttons are part of the shell (i.e. explorer.exe). If you want to change standard behavior in another process, you'll have to inject custom code to do so. And somehow convince virus protection software that your reckless attempts are legit.

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing. I'm talking about having an icon in the taskbar, or system tray as it is sometimes called: [link](http://happycatalog.com/Content/images/Guides/GettingStartedTutorial/dropbox-find-folder.png) I just want to maximize when the icon is clicked or display a menu, etc.

Comment: The part of the shell you are referring to is called *Taskbar Notification Area* ([not *tray*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/10/54831.aspx)). It provides an official interface (see [Notifications and the Notification Area](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740.aspx)). Please update your question to make the intention clear.